# PCB Grounding Plane Review

Tags: pcb, analog, grounding

I am reviewing a 6 layer board that has analog signals on the left and right side of the board.

I have always read that analog circuitry should be grouped together for easy plane segmentation. However in the real world that is not always possible, such as this case...

[image: planes]

The image labels, in text, where the analog circuitry, power circuitry, and star grounding point are. The star grounding point is where the the Vin/GND terminal block is.

The layer shown is the internal ground plane, with the darker green area being the analog plane and the whiter/lighter green area being the digital ground. All of the analog input traces are covered by the AGND plane area.

**Is this is valid grounding scheme if the bottom layer is a complete digital ground pour?**

Technically I know the grounding for analog and digital should be on the adjacent layer to the signals, but this is a basic relay output and analog input (8 bit) board and not high speed.

Comment: Your design may not be high speed but try telling that to EMI hitting the board from an external source.

Comment: Sometimes GND plane separation is a good, sometimes it is a very bad thing because it can introduce additional GND loops. Instead, check the following rules in your design: 1) Think of every! possible current loop and try to minimize all the loops with the highest signal rise time or sensitivity. 2) Two current loops should have little common trace as possible. This is done with star grounding.

Comment: My main concern with this approach is with the signals crossing the boundary between planes.  Because of the disruption of the return path, these lines would be particularly susceptible.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis yea I am aware of that. The analog signals do not have any breaks in the plane for return path. And I am hoping that the digital signals that cross the boundaries can use the bottom digital ground pour for their return path.

Comment: @zme The current in those traces crossing between the planes will actually split and use both the bottom digital pour AND will try to use your split plane, the edge cannot see the future! In the first instance I would forgo the whole split plane and star point thing totally, it is only ever a win with low frequency precision small signal stuff and usually turns out to be unnecessary. uV and uA level stuff I would worry about it, but for anything else, meh!

Comment: @DanMills Many thanks for your comment! I need a little clarification though...

      Are you saying I should use the ENTIRE internal plane as analog ground and then have the bottom layer be completely digital ground? That way the digital current return doesn't potentially split between internal and bottom layer?     

Or do you mean I should only use digital and no separate analog ground since it is only 8-bit ADC and low freq reading? If I don't split analog & digital ground, I am worried about some of the other circuitry like the relays or switching regulators disturbing the ADC lines.

Comment: @zme In the first instance I would NOT bother with separate analogue and digital planes, just have one ground plane (possibly repeated on a few layers if convenient, but if so well stitched) it is usually fine and far less likely to give you really problematic weirdness. At most I might place a few very carefully chosen slits in the planes (But NOTHING at all would cross those slits), but even that would wait until I had a prototype with just a single ground net before I started getting clever.